# Regex split by delimiter if no char before delimiter

Tags: regex, string, delimiter

`test;136;1234567890;Som/;e;Test;test /;123;qwertyuio;dfghjk`

I need to split it to:

`test`, `136`, `1234567890`, `Som/;e`, `Test`, `test /;123`, `qwertyuio`, `dfghjk`

The delimiter is ";" but there is the case that this char can also be in the text, so in this case I add "/" before ";" in my code. However, I don't know how to exlude it from the regex search.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Negative Lookbehind: `(?<!a)b ` matches "b" that's *not* preceded by "a".

Comment: What do you do if the last character in an element is a `/`?

Comment: Tomalak not Your business ;p

Comment: Wow, now that's a profoundly stupid response.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative look behind:

```
String parts = str.split("(?<!/);");
```

If you want to cater for a term that ends with a /, you could escape that too:

```
String parts = str.split("(?<!/);|(?<=//);");
```

If you want to allow terms to end with "/;", use an AST language parser.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote regex to find everything excluding those delimiters:

```
[^((?<!/);|(?<=//);)]*
```

Comment: What do you think your regex match?